# SFML Error 1 2 2, CMake failed build windows CLion

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, sfml, clion

I've been trying to set up a new SFML project and i always struggle with importing libraries. I thought that everything is fine but the errors say otherwise. Anyway, heres the code and error message:

vvvv CMake vvvv

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(SFML_try1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(SFML_try1 main.cpp)

include_directories(C:/SFML/include)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake_modules")
find_package(SFML REQUIRED system window graphics)
if(SFML_FOUND)
    include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(SFML_try1 ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
endif()

file(COPY assets DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

if(WIN32)
    file(GLOB BINARY_DEP_DLLS "${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR}/../bin/*.dll")
    file(COPY ${BINARY_DEP_DLLS} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
endif()
```

vvvv main.cpp vvvv

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

using namespace sf;    
int main()
{
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(640, 480), "screen", Style::Titlebar | Style::Close);
    Event ev;

    while(window.isOpen())
    {
        while(window.pollEvent(ev))
        {
            switch(ev.type)
            {
                case Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                    break;
                case Event::KeyPressed:
                    if(ev.key.code == Keyboard::Escape)
                        window.close();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        window.clear();
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

vvvv error message vvvv

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2020.3.2\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" 

--build C:\Users\filip\CLionProjects\SFML_try1\cmake-build-debug --target SFML_try1 -- -j 6
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** No rule to make target '/SFML/lib/sfml-system-d.lib', needed by 'SFML_try1.exe'.  Stop.
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/SFML_try1.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/SFML_try1.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [SFML_try1] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:94: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/SFML_try1.dir/all' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:101: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/SFML_try1.dir/rule' failed
Makefile:137: recipe for target 'SFML_try1' failed
```

FindSFML.cmake is located inside cmake_modules in SFML_try1 folder

I use minGW toolchain located on C drive

main SFML folder is located on C drive

I use CLion which comes with CMake pre-installed

Comment: Looks like you are missign some windows libraries in your library_path

Comment: What **origin** of `FindSFML.cmake` script which you have under `cmake_modules/`? Have you got the script from [there](https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/9781849696845/blob/f9bfa5ac9acb216d806527538948602d53729bfe/CMake/FindSFML.cmake)? Exactly this script is responsible for filling `SFML_INCLUDE_DIR` and `SFML_LIBRARIES` variable which you use in your `CMakeLists.txt`. It **smells** like the script doesn't fill that variables. Otherwise you won't need the line `include_directories(C:/SFML/include)`.

Comment: managed to get rid of some errors, turns out my MinGW version was bad but some other errors showed up...